# Setup Runtime Function Error... Error: unexpected '}' in "}"

Tags: r

I'm working through *Hands-on Programming with R*. For some reason my setup runtime function doesn't throws an error.

Specifically:

> Error: unexpected '}' in "}"

Here is my code:

```
# Create Safe Runtime Environment
setup <- functon(deck){

    # Store a Prestine Copy
    DECK <- deck

    # Deal Card Function
    deal <- function(){
        card <- deck[1, ]
        assign("deck", deck[-1, ], envir = globalenv())
        card
    }

    # Shuffle Deck Function
    shuffle <- function(){
        random <- sample(1:52, size = 52)
        assign("deck", DECK[random, ], envir = globalenv())
    }

}
```

I am using 4 spaces for tabs. But all my braces look matched?
What is going on?

EDIT:

Flagged as closed.

Comment: Well, for one you misspelled "function" in your first line of code...

Comment: @AlexA. That's exactly it. Thanks

Comment: No problem. However, I recommend removing this question since the issue is due to a simple typographical error and is unlikely to be helpful to future readers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You misspelled ´function´ at the beginning  of your code.

You wrote `functon` and you should write `function` in `setup <- functon(deck){...`

Comment: @Alex called it out. I've closed the post. Thank's for being kind about it :)